# pyspark read multiple csv files at once

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I'm using SPARK to read files in hdfs. There is a scenario, where we are getting files as chunks from legacy system in csv format.

```
ID1_FILENAMEA_1.csv
ID1_FILENAMEA_2.csv
ID1_FILENAMEA_3.csv
ID1_FILENAMEA_4.csv
ID2_FILENAMEA_1.csv
ID2_FILENAMEA_2.csv
ID2_FILENAMEA_3.csv
```

This files are loaded to FILENAMEA in HIVE using HiveWareHouse Connector, with few transformation like adding default values. Similarly we have around 70 tables. Hive tables are created in ORC format. Tables are partitioned on ID. Right now, I'm processing all these files one by one. It's taking much time.

I want to make this process much faster. Files will be in GBs.

Is there is any way to read all the FILENAMEA files at the same time and load it to HIVE tables.

Comment: You spoke about 70 tables, do all those CSV files have the same schema ? Are all the files in the same directory ? if yes, do you have to read all files in this directory or only some of them ? Can you post the code you're currently using (only the read and write part, not transformation) ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: @VincentDoba: Thanks for replying back.. Each table has unique schema. Yes, all files in same directory. I have to read all files. I'm using spark.read.csv(filename).toDF(columns).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have two methods to read several CSV files in pyspark. If all CSV files are in the same directory and all have the same schema, you can read then at once by directly passing the path of directory as argument, as follow:

```
spark.read.csv('hdfs://path/to/directory')
```

If you have CSV files in different locations or CSV files in same directory but with other CSV/text files in it, you can pass them as string representing a list of path in `.csv()` method argument, as follow:

```
spark.read.csv('hdfs://path/to/filename1,hdfs://path/to/filename2')
```

You can have more information about how to read a CSV file with Spark [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-read-csv-file-into-dataframe/)

If you need to build this list of paths from the list of files in HDFS directory, you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43215300/6807769), once you've created your list of paths, you can transform it to a string to pass to `.csv()` method with [`','.join(your_file_list)`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp)

Comment: Thanks. Is there is any way to read all csv files with wildcard? like spark.read.csv('hdfs://path/to/*FILENAMEA*')

Comment: No, it will not work, `spark.read` takes only literal file paths. You have to first list and filter your file list outside spark in plain python, then pass it as a string as argument for `spark.read.csv()`

Comment: Each file will be in GBs. Performance wise, will it be good to proceed?

Comment: Yes, performance wise it will be good to proceed. Spark is designed for this kind of use cases.

Comment: Each table will have 500 files. Is there is any limit in handling the number of files?

Comment: I don't think there is any limit, but you should test this

Comment: Thanks. Will try that and let you know..

Comment: this does not work

Comment: In spark2.0 this does not work. For Spark 2.0 you need to do this: ```spark.read.csv(['hdfs://path/to/filename1','hdfs://path/to/filename2'])```

Answer (score 3):

Using: `spark.read.csv(["path1","path2","path3"...])` you can read multiple files from different paths. But that means you have first to make a list of the paths. A list not a string of comma-separated file paths

Comment: For multiple files, I found that this was the only solution that worked for me, using PySpark, Python, and Java all installed using Anaconda on Windows 10.  I found other code patterns online, but they didn't work for me, e.g., one string of comma-separated paths, multiple paths as separate unnamed arguments to the `csv()` method,