# Read Multiple Text Files in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have many text files stored in S3, almost partitioned, but not quite. I want to read and union all of them. Keys have prefixes like:

```
s3_keys = ['s3a://prd-bucket//PROD/data/2021-04-16/part-2144.log',
 's3a://prd-bucket//PROD/data/2021-04-16/part-2146.log',
 's3a://prd-bucket//PROD/data/2021-04-16/part-2148.log',
 's3a://prd-bucket//PROD/data/2021-04-16/part-2150.log',
 's3a://prd-bucket//PROD/data/2021-04-16/part-2164.log',
 's3a://prd-bucket//PROD/data/2021-04-16/part-requeue-client-xxx.log'
]
```

I tried following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69357156/5289570), but for some strange reason, `spark.read.text` mangles the filesystem prepended in each path after the first:

```
df = (
    spark.read.option('mode', 'FAILFAST')
    .text(','.join(s3_keys))
)
```

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o40880.text. :
> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist:
> s3a://prd-bucket/PROD/data/2021-04-16/part-2144.log,s3a:/prd-bucket/PROD/data/2021-04-16/part-2146.log
> ...

Note the `s3a:/` instead of `s3a://`. Why is this happening? I'm also curious if there is a limit for this sort of path munging...something like AmazonS3Exception: Request-URI Too Large

Similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24029873/5289570), but I need a solution for PySpark (2.4) on S3.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing multiple paths separated by `,` as one string thats why you are getting below error.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o40880.text. : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: s3a://prd-bucket/PROD/data/2021-04-16/part-2144.log,s3a:/prd-bucket/PROD/data/2021-04-16/part-2146.log ...
```

Pass multiple paths as varargs or list. Try below code.

```
df = (
    spark.read.option('mode', 'FAILFAST')
    .text(s3_keys)
)
```