# Error from PySpark code pattern for reading all CSV files in a folder

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I am spinning up on Python, Spark, and Pyspark, all installed with
Anaconda on Windows 10.  According to [this
tutorial](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-read-csv-file-into-dataframe),
I should be able to read all CSV files in a folder into a `DataFrame`,
providing that all the files in the folder are CSV files:

```
# Create SparkSession object on stand-alone laptop.
# Intel Core i5-1245U has 10 cores.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[10]") \
   .appName("SparkExamples.com").getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv( r"C:\cygwin64\home\User.Name\tmp", header=True )
```

Here, folder `C:\cygwin64\home\User.Name\tmp` contains only
`zipcodes1.csv`, `zipcodes2.csv`, and `zipcodes3.csv`.  Each of these
is a replica of [`zipcodes.csv` from
GitHub](https://github.com/spark-examples/pyspark-examples/blob/master/resources/zipcodes.csv).
A `DataFrame` created from *one* of the files looks like:

```
>>> spark.read.option("header","true") \
      .csv(r"C:\cygwin64\home\User.Name\tmp\zipcodes1.csv").show(3)
+------------+-------+-----------+-------------------+-----+<...snip...>
|RecordNumber|Zipcode|ZipCodeType|               City|State|<...snip...>
+------------+-------+-----------+-------------------+-----+<...snip...>
|           1|    704|   STANDARD|        PARC PARQUE|   PR|<...snip...>
|           2|    704|   STANDARD|PASEO COSTA DEL SUR|   PR|<...snip...>
|          10|    709|   STANDARD|       BDA SAN LUIS|   PR|<...snip...>
+------------+-------+-----------+-------------------+-----+<...snip...>
```

While I can read one file, I can't read the whole `tmp` folder.  The
error is nondescript.  The Spyder console transcript is:

```
>>> spark.read.option("header","true") \
   .csv( r"C:\cygwin64\home\User.Name\tmp").show(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Cell In[19], line 1
    spark.read.option("header","true") \
  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py:727 in csv
    return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322 in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:169 in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326 in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o87.csv.
: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'
   at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
   at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
   <...snip...>
   at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

The Annex B below provides the full stack trace.  It is always the same
except for the `Py4JJavaError` line, which specifies a different
`o___.csv` file each time.  The path prefix `~` is Windows's
`%USERPROFILE%`.

Much internet searching reveals that the code pattern *should* work.
***What am I doing wrong?***

---

## Annex A: Troubleshooting

**Troubleshooting #1**

I confirmed that I can read `zipcodes[123].csv` if paths are
specified individually.  From trial-and-error, I found that I must
collect the individual paths into a list (described
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69350586/pyspark-read-multiple-csv-files-at-once#comment136222854_75292705)):

```
>>> spark.read \
   .option("header","true") \
   .csv([r"C:\cygwin64\home\User.Name\tmp\zipcodes1.csv",
         r"C:\cygwin64\home\User.Name\tmp\zipcodes2.csv",
         r"C:\cygwin64\home\User.Name\tmp\zipcodes3.csv"]
   ).show(3)
+------------+-------+-----------+-------------------+-----+<...snip...>
|RecordNumber|Zipcode|ZipCodeType|               City|State|<...snip...>
+------------+-------+-----------+-------------------+-----+<...snip...>
|           1|    704|   STANDARD|        PARC PARQUE|   PR|<...snip...>
|           2|    704|   STANDARD|PASEO COSTA DEL SUR|   PR|<...snip...>
|          10|    709|   STANDARD|       BDA SAN LUIS|   PR|<...snip...>
+------------+-------+-----------+-------------------+-----+<...snip...>
```

**Troubleshooting #2**

As a shot in the dark, I also tried to get rid of the `header`
option:

```
`spark.read.csv( r"C:\cygwin64\home\User.Name\tmp").show(3)`
```

This generates the same error and stack trace as above.

**Troubleshooting #3**

Perhaps the path needs to end in a path separator so that Spark
knows that it is a directory:

```
>>> spark.read.csv( r"C:\cygwin64\home\User.Name\tmp\", header=True )
  Cell In[1], line 1
    spark.read.csv( r"C:\cygwin64\home\User.Name\tmp\", header=True )
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Obviously, Python blew by the closing quotes.  It isn't clear why.
It can't be due to the preceding backslash because backslashes
are not special in raw strings.

**Troubleshooting #4**

Being new to Python, I could be wrong about the nonspecialness of
backslashes in raw strings, perhaps under special conditions, for
reasons that I couldn't yet fathom, e.g., when a backslash is the
final character in a string.  Therefore, I tried escaping the
terminating backslash:

```
spark.read.csv( r"C:\cygwin64\home\User.Name\tmp\\", header=True )
```

This generated the same errors and stack trace as above, *except* that
the `Py4JJavaError` line refers to `o56.csv` rather than `o87.csv`.

While this didn't solve the original problem, it did reveal a mystery
to me: Why a terminating backslash seems to be special in a raw
string.

**Troubleshooting #5**

I found that indeed, backslashes aren't normal characters in raw
strings (see [here](https://qr.ae/pKGLDB),
[here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash-in-python),
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769)).  The right
way to specify a path with a terminating backslash is:

```
spark.read.csv( r"C:\cygwin64\home\User.Name\tmp" "\\", header=True )

spark.read \
   .option("header","true") \
   .csv(r"C:\cygwin64\home\User.Name\tmp" "\\") \
   .show(3)
```

Both these statements yield the same error and stack trace as above,
however, except that the `Py4JJavaError` line refers to `o56.csv` and
`o61.csv`, respectively

**Troubleshooting #6**

To get around any uncertainty arising from how backslashes are interpreted
in string literals, I used forward slashes instead:

```
spark.read.option("header","true") \
   .csv(r"C:/cygwin64/home/User.Name/tmp/")
```

Again, this yields the same error and stack trace, except that
the `Py4JJavaError` line refers to `o48.csv`.

**Troubleshooting #7**

In response to *user238607*'s answer, I tried:

```
folder_path = "C:/cygwin64/home/User.Name/tmp/"
glob_pattern = "*.csv" # Example: Read only CSV files
data_frame = spark.read.option("pathGlobFilter", glob_pattern) \
  .option("header", True).csv(folder_path)
```

This yields the same error and stack grace, except that the
Py4JJavaError line refers to `o48.csv`.

**Troubleshooting #8**

Perhaps it is the letter-drive prefix in the full path (even though
that doesn't cause a problem when specifying individual file paths).
To check, copy the folder `tmp` containing CSV-only files into the present directory, which `pwd` shows
as `'C:\\Users\\User.Name'`.  Using Cygwin's Bash:

```
$ cp -R ~/tmp /c/Users/User.Name
$ ls -ld /c/Users/User.Name/tmp

   drwx------+ 1 User.Name None 0 Oct 12 15:21 /c/Users/User.Name/tmp

$ ls -l /c/Users/User.Name/tmp

   -rwx------+ 1 User.Name None 3035 Oct 12 15:21 zipcodes1.csv
   -rwx------+ 1 User.Name None 3035 Oct 12 15:21 zipcodes2.csv
   -rwx------+ 1 User.Name None 3035 Oct 12 15:21 zipcodes3.csv
```

In Spyder, specify the folder using raw and normal strings:

```
spark.read.option("header","true").csv(r"tmp/")
spark.read.option("header","true").csv("tmp/")
```

These two invocations generate the same error and stack trace except
that the `Py4JJavaError` line refers to `o65.csv` and `o70.csv`,
respectively.

**Troubleshooting #9**

Thanks again to *user238607* for pointing out
[this](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-hadoop-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-apache-hadoop-io-nativeio-nativeiowindows-access0ljava-lang-stringiz/amp)
possible cause and solution.  However, it looks like I have those
bases covered in my computing setup.  Essentially, environment
variable `HADOOP_HOME` must be set to the parent folder of Hadoop's
`bin` folder.  I confirmed this in Spyder:

```
>>> os.environ.get("HADOOP_HOME")
'C:\\Users\\User.Name\\AppData\\Local\\Hadoop\\2.7.1'
```

The `bin` subfolder therein contains many Hadoop-looking files (Annex
C) and no further subfolders.  As I am new to Python, Spark, and
especially Hadoop, *is there simple sanity check to confirm the proper
setup?*  I've already successfully followed SparkByExamples tutorials
in which RDD objects are created.

## Annex B: Full strack trace

The full stack trace is always the same except for the `Py4JJavaError` line, which
specifies a different `o___.csv` file each time.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Cell In[18], line 1
    spark.read \
  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py:727 in csv
    return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322 in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:169 in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326 in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o65.csv.
: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1454)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.listLeafFiles(HadoopFSUtils.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.$anonfun$parallelListLeafFilesInternal$1(HadoopFSUtils.scala:95)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.parallelListLeafFilesInternal(HadoopFSUtils.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.parallelListLeafFiles(HadoopFSUtils.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$.bulkListLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.listLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.refresh0(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.<init>(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createInMemoryFileIndex(DataSource.scala:539)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:538)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

## Anenx C: Files in %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1\bin

```
OnOutOfMemory.cmd
Start-HadoopAdminShell.cmd
Start-HadoopAdminShell.ps1
datanode.exe
datanode.xml
gplcompression.dll
hadoop
hadoop.cmd
hadoop.dll
hadoop.exp
hadoop.lib
hdfs
hdfs.cmd
hdfs.dll
hdfs.exp
hdfs.lib
hdfs_static.lib
historyserver.exe
historyserver.xml
kill-name-node
kill-secondary-name-node
libwinutils.lib
lzo2.dll
mapred
mapred.cmd
namenode.exe
namenode.xml
nodemanager.exe
nodemanager.xml
rcc
resourcemanager.exe
resourcemanager.xml
secondarynamenode.exe
secondarynamenode.xml
snappy-c.obj
snappy-sinksource.obj
snappy-stubs-internal.obj
snappy.dll
snappy.dll.intermediate.manifest
snappy.exp
snappy.lastbuildstate
snappy.lib
snappy.obj
snappy.write.1.tlog
timelineserver.exe
timelineserver.xml
winutils.exe
yarn
yarn.cmd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to *user238607*'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77270651/error-from-pyspark-code-pattern-for-reading-all-csv-files-in-a-folder/77271290?noredirect=1#comment136257384_77271290), the solution was to simply [copy `hadoop.dll` to `c:\Windows\System32`](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-hadoop-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-apache-hadoop-io-nativeio-nativeiowindows-access0ljava-lang-stringiz/amp).

**@user238607:**  This answer really belongs to you, so feel free to post it and I'll take down mine.  Though with your rep, I doubt that you're that concerned about it.  I'm interested in providing an answer promptly so that the community bot doesn't see this Q&A as useless and remove it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution adapter from the link :

https://tsaiprabhanj.medium.com/pyspark-pathglobfilter-option-b1ca31923a13

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName("PathGlobFilterExample") \
.getOrCreate()

# Specify the path to the folder containing files and the glob pattern
folder_path = "../data/salaryDirForStreamingMulti/"
glob_pattern = "*.csv" # Example: Read only CSV files

# Read files using pathGlobFilter
data_frame = spark.read.option("pathGlobFilter", glob_pattern).option("header", True).csv(folder_path)

# Show the content of the DataFrame
data_frame.show(n=100, truncate=False)

# Stop the Spark session
spark.stop()
```

Output :

```
+-------+-------+-------+-----------+
|Column1|Column2|Column3|21-Jun     |
+-------+-------+-------+-----------+
|A      |File2  |B7     |2770574045 |
|A      |File2  |B8     |87593986976|
|A      |File2  |B9     |141321103  |
|A      |File3  |B3     |8860695817 |
|A      |File3  |B4     |346870273  |
|A      |File3  |B5     |5000       |
|A      |File1  |B1     |56804709552|
|A      |File1  |B2     |0          |
|A      |File1  |B3     |8860695817 |
+-------+-------+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the same error and stack trace.  I've captured this under **Troubleshooting #7** in the originally posted question.

Comment: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-hadoop-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-apache-hadoop-io-nativeio-nativeiowindows-access0ljava-lang-stringiz/amp/

Comment: Thanks again, but to my newbie eyes, it looks like I have that base covered.  I've logged the details under **Troubleshooting #9**.

Comment: Why aren't you using Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Comment: I rely on Cygwin on more than just the OS work-alike layer, but also the countless tools/environments (e.g. X-windows, Vim, LaTeX).  I rely on its package manager for version compatibility.  Having to get to know something new like WSL means an even greater detour than my current detour to spin up on Python and Spark.  My current use of PySpark has no dependence on Cygwin.

Comment: Of course, I don't know the full workflow but you can chain things together. Pyspark is same whether in WIndows environment or Linux environment (e.g. through WSL). Do your windows stuff, call pyspark workflow within WSL and then get back results and do your windows stuff again.

Comment: 1. Close and reload the command line or terminal to initialize these variables. Sometimes you may also need to put hadoop.dll file into the C:/Windows/System32 folder.

2. However, if it still doesn’t work, try to restart your system as some of the above settings would get the effect with the restart.

Did you do these two additional things?

Comment: Doh. I totally intended to copy `hadoop.dll` to `c:\Windows\System32`, but forgot. As it turns out, that was the solution. ***Did you want to post it as the answer?*** P.S. `HADOOP_HOME` was properly set for a long time and many laptop reboots. **P.P.S.** Your example code included a `spark.stop()`, but since I'm using the console, should I avoid that until I'm ready to terminate Spyder? My readings show that it s a SparkSession rather than a SparkContext, but the latter gets killed anyway by stopping the former.

Comment: As for WSL, I'm trying to contain the number of new horizons that I am simultaneously confronting. Do you see that it makes much difference in the Spyder/Python/Spark/Hadoop integration issues that emerge?

Comment: I would actually recommend to experiment stuff in Linux like environment if you are doing these stuff from job perspective. Because developers are more active there and better support on Linux platform

Comment: It's very easy to get started with WSL. Much better experience than cygwin.

Comment: I not so much worried about getting started as I am about become efficient. I was able to install a Linux VM on a previous laptop and got it running in little time.  Realistically, however, it took a lot longer to become savvy because of differences in permissions elevation, different copy/paste buffers, how different apps respond to zoom scaling, etc. I also rely on Cygwin to maintain compatibility between SW component versions, especially LaTeX and X-Windows, the latter being very complex and something I haven't really understood despite trying over decades. I'll keep Linux in mind!

Comment: WSL [looks nifty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S34znhI-pRA), but it automatically updates.  That could introduce challenges when they are least welcome.  At least for Ubuntu running on WSL, it relies on `apt` for package management and version compatibility.  Also, it is lightweight, in contrast to VirtualBox, which requires that I allot the guest OS its own RAM and disk space. I like what I see, and note that the automatic updating applies only to the kernel rather than the packages.

Comment: Yup cygwin, virtual box, those are all old stuff. MS is fully committed to bring Linux tooling to Windows so that developers don't leave their platform.