# Reading Multiple CSV files from different paths into my pyspark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read multiple files from different path and getting below error.

> pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: [PATH_NOT_FOUND]
> Path does not exist: file:/D:/Dir1/Dir1.1/File1.csv,
> D:/Dir2/Dir2.1/File2.csv.

These are 2 files with same schema but in two different locations on local machine.

When I read these files into dataframes individually I can see the output. However I cannot get both these files to create one single dataframe.

the code is as follows.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").appName("Import_from_multiplefiles").getOrCreate()

df2 = spark.read.format('csv').load('/D:/Dir1/Dir1.1/File1.csv, D:/Dir2/Dir2.1/File2.csv')
df2.show(5, False)
```

Kindly help and suggest possible error and resolution.
Also I am interested in knowing whether two different files(Different Schema) can be read into one single dataFrame

Comment: `df2 = spark.read.format('csv').load(['D:/Dir1/Dir1.1/File1.csv', 'D:/Dir2/Dir2.1/File2.csv'])` instead

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. However even separating both the paths is not helping. I am using IntelliJ 2023.2.4 IDE. It automatically assumes multiple arguments as different options like path, format, schema etc.

Comment: This may be my own ignorance, but I don't see how an IDE would make a difference here. Furthermore the list `['D:/Dir1/Dir1.1/File1.csv', 'D:/Dir2/Dir2.1/File2.csv']` would be a single argument to the [`load()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.load.html) method. With this change are you getting the exact same error message or something different?

Comment: I believe that is only a feature of the `csv()` method. You could also do `spark.read.format('csv').load()` in which case a single parameter of a string or list would be required once again.

Comment: sorry my bad, I did not pay attention to square bracket earlier. However I referred to some articles ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69350586/pyspark-read-multiple-csv-files-at-once) where the path was separated by commas without any list. Its working now and Thanks a lot for helping here. appreciate it :)