# PySpark: How to read multiple CSV files with different column positions most efficiently

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read multiple CSV files in a directory using Spark in the most efficient way possible. Unfortunately, I haven't found a better way to do this other than reading each file individually, which is quite time consuming.

From what I understood, the most efficient way to read multiple CSV files is to use the `*` as follows:

```py
df = spark.read.format('csv') \
        .option('header', 'true') \
        .load('/path/to/csv/folder/*.csv')
```

However, although it is very fast, it does not perform the union by column name, but follows the column indices.
If, for instance, the directory contains the following two CSV files:

`1.csv`:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 | 6 |

`2.csv`:

| A | C |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 8 |

the previous operation will merge them like this:

`df`:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 | 6 |
| 7 | **8** | **NULL** |

This is obviously **incorrect** since the last row should read `7|NULL|8`.

Well, I was able to solve this problem by reading each file individually and then doing a `unionByName` with the `allowMissingColumns` parameter set to `True`, as follows:

```py
dfs = []
for filename in list_file_names('/path/to/csv/folder'):
    dfs.append(spark.read.format('csv') \
        .option('header', 'true') \
        .load('/path/to/csv/folder/{filename}')
    )
union_df = dfs[0]
for df in dfs[1:]:
    union_df = union_df.unionByName(df, allowMissingColumns=True)
```

This works as expected, but as I read each file individually, it is much slower. For 100 small CSV files in hdfs on the same machine, the first (but wrong) method finishes in around **6 seconds**, while the second takes **16 seconds**.

**So my question is, can I achieve the same result in PySpark by performing only one read operation as in the first method?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I achieve the same result in PySpark by performing only one read operation

Sadly you can't use the spark data source api in one go, as you noticed due to schema merging limitations.

Instead you could optimize your union approach by first reading the header of each file, grouping them by category of csv and then unioning each category of file.

Getting all first row associated with the file path can be achieved in pure Python [with boto for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618468/read-a-file-line-by-line-from-s3-using-boto#39745836).

Then reading a list of files in one go can be done with the [comma separated list of path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69357156/3865083).

While in two steps, if you have few category of csv, this should be much faster than unioning every single files.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @parisni!

After following your suggestion, I have implemented a faster solution as follows:

First, I declared a function to read the headers of the CSV files and determine the minimum number of `unionByName` operations required.

```py
def read_headers():
    """
    Read headers from the CSV files and return them as a dict, where the key is a tuple of the indices
    of the columns of interest, and the value is the list of file paths
    Note: To minimize the number of unionByName operations, we only look at the indexes of the columns 
    of interest in the subsequent queries
    """
    headers = {}
    for filename in list_file_names(DATASET_PATH):
        path = f'{DATASET_PATH}/{filename}'
        header = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(path).columns
        # Another way to go is with smart_open as follows:
        # header = smart_open.smart_open(path).readline().strip()
        key = tuple(header.index(c) for c in COLUMNS_OF_INTEREST)
        headers[key] = headers.get(key, []) + [filename]
    return headers
```

Then I run the `unionByName` as follows:

```py
headers = read_headers()
dfs = []
for filenames in headers.values():
    dfs.append(spark.read.format('csv')
               .option('header', 'true')
               .load(filenames))
union_df = reduce(lambda x, y: x.unionByName(y, allowMissingColumns=True), dfs)
```

And in case anyone is wondering, the `list_file_names` function is defined as follows:

```py
def list_file_names(directory_path):
    """
    List all files in a given directory on the hdfs filesystem
    """
    file_status_objects = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()).listStatus(
        sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(directory_path)
    )
    return sorted([str(file.getPath().getName()) for file in file_status_objects])
```