Read CSV Files into Spark DataFrame using For loop in PySpark
I am trying to import csv files saved in an Azure data container into a spark dataframe using a for loop. I am running this code on Azure Databricks. The for loop runs without any error. However I am unable to access the dataframe by its name.
I am able to access the teams dataframe by using df_spark.show()
Please could you help me.
'''
for df_spark in ['athletes', 'coaches','entriesgender','medals','teams']:
    df_spark=spark.read.csv('/mnt/data/raw-data/'+df_spark+'.csv',header=True)
    df_spark.show()

athletes.show(n=5) # Error: It wouldn't recognise the spark dataframe by name.

'''
The code

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75292705/3238085  take a look at this answer.

Sorry - It did not help. I need each file to be imported into a spark dataframe which I can later refer by name of the spark dataframe

thats not how spark works. Thats not how any language works.
You are creating dataframe with df_spark variable anf overwriting it. How can you get the athletes variable which you have not created.

Can you try this?
datasets = ['athletes', 'coaches', 'entriesgender', 'medals', 'teams']

dfs = {}

for dataset in datasets:
    df_spark = spark.read.csv('/mnt/data/raw-data/' + dataset + '.csv', header=True)
    dfs[dataset] = df_spark
    df_spark.show()

dfs['athletes'].show(n=5)


Thanks Prathik. I will try and get back.

The easiest way to do it.

In case all file have same schema

from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name
df_spark=spark.read.csv('/mnt/data/raw-data/',header=True)
df_spark = df_spark.withcolumn("file_name",input_file_name())
athletes = df_spark.filter(df_spark.file_name.contains('athletes')

athletes.show(n=5)


In case schema is different

<create schema containing all fields of all files in directory>
df_spark=spark.read.format("csv").schema(customSchema).load('/mnt/data/raw-data/',header=True)
df_spark = df_spark.withcolumn("file_name",input_file_name())
athletes = df_spark.filter(df_spark.file_name.contains('athletes')
athletes.show(n=5)

